# Checking if a View is an EmptyView in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Is there anyway of checking if a view added using ViewBuilder is an EmptyView. Here is a code sample:

```
struct ViewAsVariable<TestView:View>: View {
    
    @ViewBuilder var aView:TestView
    var body: some View {
        if aView === EmptyView(){
            Text( "view is empty")
        }
        else{
            aView
        }
    }
    
    init(destinationView: TestView ) {
        self.aView = destinationView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should test what type the associated generic type is rather than the instance of that type

```
if TestView.self == EmptyView.self { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Type checks at runtime are rather *unswifty*.

And unlike UIKit SwiftUI is declarative. You should **tell** the view that it's empty rather than **asking** for it

```
struct ViewAsVariable<TestView:View>: View {
    private let isEmpty : Bool

    @ViewBuilder var aView:TestView
    var body: some View {
        if isEmpty {
            Text( "view is empty")
        }
        else {
            aView
        }
    }
    
    init(destinationView: TestView, isEmpty: Bool = false ) {
        self.isEmpty = isEmpty
        self.aView = destinationView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a type check because `EmptyView` isn't going to give you anything useful to work with; use `Never` instead.

```swift
struct ViewAsVariable<TestView: View>: View {
  let aView: TestView?

  init(destinationView: TestView = Never?.none) {
    aView = destinationView
  }

  var body: some View {
    if let aView {
      aView
    } else {
      Text("view is empty")
    }
  }
}
```